# How to pass icon as variable in react from stories. As is would be for user to select

Tags: reactjs

here i want to pass image as a variable in stories and want user to select the image as a variable

Stories

```
`storiesOf('DomainUserNameForm', module).add('default', () =>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <DomainUserNameForm clientLogo={wsllogo}/>
  </ThemeProvider>
);`


Code:

    render() {
    const { firstName, lastName, userName, sendEmail, error, valid} = this.state;
    const { clientLogo } = this.props;

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Header />
        <RegistrationHeader
          title="Join the TaskValue team for WSL &SM"
          subtitle="Your name will be displayed next to your tasks in TaskValue"
          background={clientlogo}
        />
        <FormContainer>
          <Form>

          </Form>
        </FormContainer>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Above is the code where user selected logo would be called. It shows the erroe clientlogo is not defined

Comment: shouldn't `ThemeProvider` accept that prop instead of `DomainUserNameForm`?

Comment: send the full component code of the  render() { ... }